# Erro PLS-00324 ao criar Package Body

Tags: oracle

Ao compilar o Package Body abaixo, foi me retornado o seguinte erro:

> Erro(16,8): PLS-00324: o atributo de cursor não pode ser aplicado ao não-cursor 'V_CD_ESTADO'

O que deu a entender é que o atributo retornado pelo cursor não pode ser atribuído para a variável. Mas a variável é do mesmo tipo do retorno do `SELECT`... Estranho, não?

Já fiz exatamente o mesmo (atribuir o valor de um cursor a uma variável não-cursor) em outra função e deu certo.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PCK_TB_ESTADO
IS
  FUNCTION FNC_VALIDA_ESTADO
  (P_CD_ESTADO IN TB_FUNCIONARIO.CD_ESTADO%TYPE)
  RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    CURSOR C_VERIFICA
    IS
      SELECT CD_ESTADO
      FROM TB_FUNCIONARIO
      WHERE CD_ESTADO = P_CD_ESTADO;
    V_CD_ESTADO TB_FUNCIONARIO.CD_ESTADO%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN C_VERIFICA;
      FETCH C_VERIFICA INTO V_CD_ESTADO;
    IF V_CD_ESTADO%NOTFOUND THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
    CLOSE C_VERIFICA;
  END;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

O teu problema é que estás a aplicar o atributo `%NOTFOUND` a um identificador `V_CD_ESTADO` sem que este tenha sido declarado como um `cursor`.

Precisas de declarar:

```
CURSOR V_CD_ESTADO
```

---

## [Documentação:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/plsus.htm#PLS-00324)

> **PLS-00324: cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'string'**
>
> **Cause:** This error occurs when a cursor-attribute ("%FOUND", "%NOTFOUND", "%ROWS", "%IS_OPEN", etc.) appears following an
> identifier that is not declared as a cursor or cursor variable. It
> occurs, for example, if the variable name my_cur in my_cur%FOUND was
> not properly declared as a cursor or if the variable declaration was
> placed incorrectly in the block structure.
>
> **Action:** Check the spelling and declaration of the identifier. Also confirm that the declaration is placed correctly in the block
> structure.

Que traduzido:

> **PLS-00324: O atributo cursor não pode ser aplicado a um não-cursor 'string'**
>
> **Causa:** Este erro ocorre quando um cursor do atributo ("%FOUND", "%NOTFOUND", "%ROWS", "%IS_OPEN", etc.) aparece a seguir a um identificador que não é declarado como um cursor ou variável de cursor. Ela ocorre, por exemplo, se o nome da variável my_cur em my_cur%FOUND não foi devidamente declarado como um cursor ou se a declaração da variável foi colocado incorrectamente na estrutura do bloco.
>
> **Acção:** Verifique a ortografia e declaração do identificador. Também confirmam que a declaração é colocada correctamente na estrutura do bloco.